# jQuery, Masonry & Image handling?

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress

I've got jQuery Masonry working on my site

http://www.lovejungle.com/dev/testenvironment/?cat=4

But for the life of me, I cannot work out how the images are handled.

Is there a method where it grabs the post featured image? Or is there a line of code that grabs it?

This is the code I'm using for my index.php and categories.php pages

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=15'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="box col<?php echo rand(2,4); ?>">
<span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PostThumb', true); ?>" alt="" />
<span class="ex"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
</a>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

The code is from this tutorial 
http://digwp.com/2010/08/randomized-grid-of-posts/#comment-1175

I know this needs to change

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PostThumb', true); ?>" alt="" />
```

Or it might be that my input method for images is not right.

This is an example of what i'm aiming for 
http://thoughtandtheory.com/collection/

I'm still unclear about how images are handled?

Comment: I'm afraid to step into the love jungle. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry haha, Love Jungle is a youth clothing brand from Sydney Australia. Nothing raunchy! (and the link above is a dev/test site) so it's basically a twentyten theme modified

Comment: @Alex here is a screen shot of the site. Hopefully it works - http://www.lovejungle.com/dev/testenvironment/images/masonry_screen.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so.. if i get you right, you'd like to get the post images in the loop? just the thumbnails of it or the big image? should the images be links to the article?

i'd create main category where all your posts for the filter are in. then create a custom query for that category like this:

```
<?php $YourQuery = new WP_Query(array('cat=11', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); if ($YourQuery->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($YourQuery->have_posts()) : $YourQuery->the_post(); ?>
```

while getting all the posts you could then assign the recent category to the div and use this for the filter:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category ) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>">
```

and then get the images inside that div. check for the thumbs first and define their height & width (or skip that part if you don't want to have a grid like optic). then, while calling the image, assign the category to the image so you could use these for the filter:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('160,230,true');}
elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, "HomeThumbnail", true) != '') 
{ 
?>

<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();   ?>" class="<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){echo $category->cat_name . ' ';} ?> ex" />

       <?php 
}

else {
echo "<img class=\"ex\" src=\"". get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/images/placeholder.jpg\" alt=\"Default Post Image\" />";
 }
   ?>  
</a>
```

in the last part i assigned a placeholder image so you could test the environment without having all the images uploaded yet.

that should give you a go in the right direction...

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for your answer! I was really just after an explanation as to how this blog [ http://thoughtandtheory.com/collection/ ] gets it's pictures for posts (so I could incorporate the same technique)... Your code looks a bit more in-depth so i'll have to have a sit down with it tomorrow night. I'll post back with my results

Comment: i just checked the digwp articel and your code seems to be fine. how are you integrating the pictures in the post? just via the post edit field or are you assigning them as the post-thumbnail? that could be your problem..

Comment: This post shows a picture i've added via the post edit field http://www.lovejungle.com/dev/testenvironment/?p=1

Comment: The above post ( http://www.lovejungle.com/dev/testenvironment/?p=1 ) also has a Featured Image of the same image. I can get the featured image to show via this line of code <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?> . 
Which having just re-read your code all makes sense now. 
Here is another good example of what i'm shooting for... http://www.dazeddigital.com/

Comment: yes, I managed to get it working with some of the following code mixed with your suggestion above. http://d.pr/LkoE
Now, how could I control the width of the thumbnail to be the same as the width of the grid column it's loaded into? (eg. if you refresh the category it displays different portions of image)

Comment: well.. i guess you should open a new question for this, since it's a different topic. but it's not that easy.. usually the witdh of the image defines in which grid column the article fits and i haven't seen it the other way round yet. but i'm also working on some post-thumbnail issue right now so if i stumble upon something i'll get back at you.

Comment: oh.. and please mark this question als solved if it helped you. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, your answer really helped me out!